# SQL Server Select Top

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a new table in SQL Server.  I would like to insert rows from another table, and I want to include Name, Team, Receptions, Yards, and Touchdowns.  I would like to select the top six receivers with the most yards.

My query looks like this at the moment:

```
insert into ProBowl (Name, Team, Receptions, Yards, Touchdowns)
select top 6 from Widereceivers;
```

When I do this, it just returns the first six rows - but it does not sort by yardage.  How can I do this?

Comment: By adding an `order by` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Order By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9zc0283%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in Sql.

From the documentation I linked above:

> [ASC]
>   Specifies an ascending order for the query results. ASC is the default order for ORDER BY.
>   [DESC]
>   Specifies a descending order for the query results.

To order by descending, do this:

```
SELECT TOP 6 * FROM Widereceivers ORDER BY yards DESC;
```

To order by ascending, do this:

```
SELECT TOP 6 * FROM Widereceivers ORDER BY yards ASC;
```

Comment: Might want to check that second query.

Comment: @alroc - thanks for the edit and the heads-up.  My professor always used to warn me the danger of haste and cut-and-paste.

Answer (score 4):

It's not sorting by yardage because you haven't told it to sort by yardage.

```
select top 6 * from widereceivers order by yardage desc;
```